# How to emulate in C# the object pinning of the .NET CLR hosting when passing arbitrary objects

Tags: c#, r, com, clr

I am working on a [package](http://rclr.codeplex.com) in R hosting the Microsoft .NET CLR. While adding features I bumped in an issue likely to do with .net object pinning, or rather the lack thereof. Details are [there](https://rclr.codeplex.com/workitem/33) but I'll hopefully give enough here:

**Pre-existing things, that worked fine**

R objects indirectly reference .NET objects via COM variants, by very nature of MS CLR hosting: R_externalptr -> SomeCustomCppClass -> _variant_t (if Microsoft) -> .NET_obj

The mscorlib CLR hosting layer is used to call managed code, e.g.:

```
VARIANT * vtResult;
typePtr->InvokeMember_3(staticMethodName, 
    static_cast<BindingFlags>(BindingFlags_InvokeMethod | BindingFlags_Static | BindingFlags_Public), 
    NULL, vtEmpty, methodArgs, vtResult);
```

When disposed, there is a mechanism in R triggering the release of the variant, like so. All works fine.

```
SEXP clrSexp; // R external pointer
_variant_t * objptr = get_the_variant(clrSexp)
delete objptr;
```

This has all been working just fine.

**Changes, and the issue**

Basically I want some more suitable conversion from C# to sensible R equivalents, beyond the CLR hosting behavior. I have reasons to implement this in C# rather than growing the C/C++ layer. Glossing over extraneous, the key code is, I believe:

```
private const Int32 SizeOfNativeVariant = 16;
private static IntPtr CreateVariant(object obj) {
    // GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned); // Usually, will throw exception.
    IntPtr pVariant = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(SizeOfNativeVariant); // or AllocCoTaskMem?
    Marshal.GetNativeVariantForObject(obj, pVariant);
    return pVariant;
}
```

And the end-to-end result actually largely works (unit tests). But, if aggressively forcing CLR and R garbage collection in one unit test, a crash occurs (MSVC++ runtime reports a failed _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID assertion) when disposing of a variant_t:

```
_variant_t * objptr = get_the_variant(clrSexp)
delete objptr; // <== debugger shows a VT_EMPTY type, where I'd expect a VT_UNKNOWN
```

If I try to pin the object with `GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);` for most objects it will throw an ArgumentException “Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data.”.

So, it is a bit of a mystery what the CLR hosting layer does to apparently pin arbitrary objects. If someone with a mastery of these rather arcane things can shed some light as to if and how I can replicate this in C#, I'd much appreciate.